# INSERT query priority

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to increase execute priority on some INSERT statements in my application. Here is how these statements looks

```
INSERT HIGH_PRIORITY INTO tbl values(......)
```

So far, so good. When I run mtop on the server (where database is) I see that the queries with HIGH_PRIORITY keyword are still on the execute queue and they are waiting to some other query to be executed.

How to get better priority on my queries ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL server engine 5.1 or higher this is the reason, according the documentation:

> If you specify HIGH_PRIORITY, it overrides the effect of the
>   --low-priority-updates option if the server was started with that option. It also causes concurrent inserts not to be used.
>
> LOW_PRIORITY and HIGH_PRIORITY affect only storage engines that use
>   only table-level locking (such as MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE).

I assume in your case that you use the InnoDB storage engine, consider changing it at least for these specific tables. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Comment: Then the priority should work as described, what is the version of the MySQL server? If you use 4.x maybe the priority is not supported correctly or it is buggy...